# Button press leads to app stopping, failure with Textview change?

Tags: java, android

This is my first attempt to make an app, I try to learn everything on my own.
I encountered this problem:
Sorry for bad coding, still learning :)

In my main `Activity` is a button that leads to this activity, it should change the text of the `Textview` and then show this activity

Thank you for your help!

when I leave out the part:

```
        TextView aufgabe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aufgabe);
        String aufgabentext = String.valueOf(zahl1)+" "+operatorstring+" "+String.valueOf(zahl2)+" = X";
        aufgabe.setText(aufgabentext);
```

it works properly, but of course without any changes

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int zahl1 = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
    int zahl2 = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
    int operator = rand.nextInt(1);
    int sum;

    String operatorstring;
    if(operator == 0){
        operatorstring = "-";
        sum = zahl1 - zahl2;
    }else {
        operatorstring = "+";
        sum = zahl1 + zahl2;
    }

    TextView aufgabe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aufgabe);
    String aufgabentext = String.valueOf(zahl1)+" "+operatorstring+" "+String.valueOf(zahl2)+" = X";
    aufgabe.setText(aufgabentext);


    setContentView(R.layout.firsttask);
}
```

The new activity should show a text with: [number] [+|-] [number] =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `setContentView(R.layout.firsttask);` just after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

You're trying to access your `TextView` before inflating your layout.

Comment: Could you add some explanation about why this line should be used the earlier possible ?

Comment: Thank you very much!
I thought I change the Text before showing the activity so it doesn't change when users see it.